# Appharbor build failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor

I'm trying to push a project in Appharbor but it always ends up with an error

```
2>Done Building Project "D:\temp\0uju11ye.si5\input\ShareRide\ShareRide.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
     1>Done Building Project "D:\temp\0uju11ye.si5\input\ShareRide.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "D:\temp\0uju11ye.si5\input\ShareRide.sln" (default target) (1) ->
       "D:\temp\0uju11ye.si5\input\ShareRide\ShareRide.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
       (_CopyWebApplicationLegacy target) -> 
         C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Assets\Images\imagen_grua.jpg" because it was not found. [D:\temp\0uju11ye.si5\input\ShareRide\ShareRide.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.51
```

There's quite a bit more logged. Also that image that's "not finding" it's actually in the project, I don't really know why is it giving that error.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this by double checking that `imagen_grua.jpg` missing and I found it, just `removed it from project` and cleaned solution, rebuild solution. Pushed to Appharbor and it worked finally.